# How to use a sum function within an if condition in python

Tags: python

I am attempting to find the sum of `prices` for vehicles in the `state` of `texas`.  Below is the code that I have attempted

```
Autos = [
{'make': 'Jeep', 'Model': 'Wrangler', 'price': 35000, 'state': 'colorado'},
{'make': 'Jeep', 'Model': 'Wrangler', 'price': 33250, 'state': 'texas'},
{'make': 'Jeep', 'Model': 'Wrangler', 'price': 52300, 'state': 'colorado'},
{'make': 'Jeep', 'Model': 'Wrangler', 'price': 75000, 'state': 'colorado'},
{'make': 'Jeep', 'Model': 'Wrangler', 'price': 28500, 'state': 'texas'},
{'make': 'Jeep', 'Model': 'Wrangler', 'price': 35000, 'state': 'colorado'},
]

for d in Autos:
    if d['state'] == 'texas':
        sum([d['price']])
```

I am able to get the list of prices using the following.  But I need the sum to calculate the average.

```
for d in Autos:
    if d['state'] == 'texas':
        print(d['price'])
        
33250
28500
```

Comment: "I am able to get the list of prices using the following", No, you aren't - you are able to *display* the prices in order. That's a completely different thing. If you were able to get the list, then you could simply pass that list to `sum`. You should try to think about the problem in those separate steps, and you should *study techniques for processing a list*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```py
sum(auto["price"] for auto in Autos if auto["state"] == "texas")
```